# Project Start ERROR Android Studio 2.2.3 Gradle "MyAPP" project refresh failed. Cause:unknown

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I am new to AndroidStudio and I have installed Android Studio 2.2.3 from official website. After installation when I created my empty/basic project ("hello world") program couldn't built. I do not know why this happened, cause I haven't changed/added anything. The JDK that I installed with Android Studio is 8u11. I have tried a few solutions(delete .gradle, delete gradle-*- files from gradle lib) which I found on similar question here, error stays the same. Also tried to reinstall program, but without any help. Please help me! I am getting sick of this error.

[This the error log that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yapgK.jpg)

Comment: show me your code. Its a null pointer exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Funny thing is, that there is no "my" code, like I said, I just created a new project with empty activity and error appears right after project is loaded.